# Automated encoding repair in R for foreign characters

Tags: r, encoding, web-scraping, character-encoding, rvest

I have a `.csv` data frame `df` with 100,000+ rows and two columns representing city and country names (scraped with permission from a website), where a subset of the data look like below:

```
df <- read.csv("country_dat.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
df
  city                     country
1 Huntsville, Alabama      US
2 Nyn_shamn                Sweden
3 J__li                    Finland
```

The file includes multiple encodings so I tried the following to fix the encoding errors in the post-processing:

```
library(rvest)
guess_encoding(df$city[2])

     encoding language confidence
1  ISO-8859-1       en       0.30
2  ISO-8859-2       hu       0.20
3       UTF-8                0.15
4    UTF-16BE                0.10
5    UTF-16LE                0.10
6   Shift_JIS       ja       0.10
7     GB18030       zh       0.10
8      EUC-JP       ja       0.10
9      EUC-KR       ko       0.10
10       Big5       zh       0.10

repair_encoding(df$city[2])

Best guess: ISO-8859-1 (56% confident)
[1] "Nyn_shamn"
```

which is obviously not working. Is it possible to automate the repair encoding process without having to scrape the website again?

**EDIT:** The desired output would look like below:

```
  city                     country           city_fixed
1 Huntsville, Alabama      US                Huntsville, Alabama
2 Nyn_shamn                Sweden            Nynäshamn
3 J__li                    Finland           Jääli
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide your desired output? "'s-Hertogenbusch' is a valid Dutch city name, so I do not understand why this is "obviously not working".

Another option might be to use `en2cutf8()` which should harmonize your input - however, I'm not sure if you might lose any information then.

Comment: Tried `enc2utf8()` but didn't work. Both this and `guess_encoding` output the same result with underscores instead of special characters.

Comment: Could you provide a small sample of the .csv file so that it's possible to play around a bit? Otherwise it's quite difficult to test possible solutions